How to sort a list of instances of a C++ class
I'm writing a C++ program for a 2D RPG game, using the SDL2 libraries. I have a class named Entity that has a property named worldY:
class Entity 
{
public:
        ...
    // coordinate mondo: la mappa del mondo
    int worldX = 0, worldY = 0;
}

In another class GamePanel I declare one of its properties:
std::list<Entity> entityList;
std::vector<Entity> npc;

The NPC vector is filled with instances of the:
class NPC_OldMan : public Entity

in this way:
for (int i = 0; i < npc.size(); i++)
{
    if (!npc.at(i).name.empty())
    {
        entityList.push_back(npc.at(i));
    }
}

Now I would like the entityList to be sorted in ascending order by the worldY property.
i.e. if npc1 has worldY = 10 and npc2 has worldY = 5, then in the entityList I want to have npc2 and then npc1.
Using the following includes:
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>

I was thinking of using this:
std::sort(entityList.begin(), entityList.end(), [](Entity e1, Entity e2) 
    {
    // Custom comparison logic 
    return e1.worldY < e2.worldY; // this sorts in ascending order 
    });

But I can't compile it, because it gives me this error:
Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details Error   C2676   binary '-': 'const std::_List_unchecked_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator with [ _Ty=Entity ]   My2DGame_21 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include\algorithm 8165         
I also tried to do this, but the result doesn't change, I always get the same error:
std::sort(entityList.begin(), entityList.end(), [](const auto& a, const auto& b) { return a.worldY < b.worldY; });

How should I fix my code? I do not know how to do. Is there another way to do this sorting of the list ?

std::list::sort is what you want to use. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort std::sort requires random access iterators and std::list does not provide those.

You cannot sort std::list with std::sort. Instead, use entityList.sort(). But do you really need std::list? It is usually the worst container possible for any given job.

Does this answer your question? Sort list using STL sort function

thank you all for your advice: Retired Ninja, n. m. could be an AI, Dmitry Gordon. If I use std::vector entityList and not std::list entityList, how should I write to do the sorting (from smallest to largest value of entityList.worldY) ?

Sidenote: Be reminded that when you fill a std::list<Entity> with objects of type NPC_OldMan that is derived from Entity, then the list forgets that the objects originally were of type NPC_OldMan. It's called "object slicing". Do you really want it?

no, j6t. I solved it by using instead of std::list entityList, std::vector entityList:
// Overloading < operator
bool operator<(const Entity& obj) const { return worldY < obj.worldY; }
// Sorting the vector of custom objects
sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());

You can use std::list::sort:
entityList.sort([](const auto& a, const auto& b) { return a.worldY < b.worldY; })

or just use std::vector to use std::sort.

Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since another user already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up instead of repeating the same information.

Unfortunately I realized that my solution to the previous post didn't give me the right order.  So I created a new request, inserting a more complete example code.  Sorry for the repetition of the post.

This is correct:
std::sort(entityList.begin(), entityList.end(),
[ ](Entity* a, Entity* b)->bool { return a->worldY < b->worldY; });

You can sort std::list using its member function sort():
entityList.sort([](const auto& a, const auto& b) { return a.worldY < b.worldY; });

However, if you don't have a special reason to use std::list, use std::vector instead. In this case, the source code you showed will work.

You can't do that with std::list. std::sort requires a pair of random access iterator and std::list is obviously not the case.
Most probably you need to use std::vector instead.

thank you all for your advice: Retired Ninja, n. m. could be an AI, Dmitry Gordon.
If I use std::vector entityList and not std::list entityList, how should I write to do the sorting (from smallest to largest value of entityList.worldY) ?

@malloy Just in a way you tried to do with std::list, std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const auto& left, const auto& right) {  return left.worldY < right.worldY; })

I found the solution that I report here with an example similar to mine:
#include <algorithm> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector> 
using namespace std; 
  
// creating a custom class 
class MyClass { 
public: 
    int data; 
  
    MyClass(int a) 
        : data(a) 
    { 
    } 
  
    // Overloading < operator 
    bool operator<(const MyClass& obj) const
    { 
        return data < obj.data; 
    } 
}; 
  
int main() 
{ 
    // Vector of custom objects 
    vector<MyClass> vec; 
    vec.push_back(MyClass(30)); 
    vec.push_back(MyClass(10)); 
    vec.push_back(MyClass(20)); 
    vec.push_back(MyClass(40)); 
  
    // Sorting the vector of custom objects 
    sort(vec.begin(), vec.end()); 
  
    // Printing  the vector 
    cout << "Sorted vector: "; 
    for (auto& obj : vec) 
        cout << obj.data << " "; 
    cout << endl; 
  
    return 0; 
}


Unfortunately I realized that my solution to the previous post didn't give me the right order.  So I created a new request, inserting a more complete example code.  Sorry for the repetition of the post.
